# Android game surfaceview background image

Tags: android, drawable, surfaceview, 2d-games

I'm making and android game using `SurfaceView`, and I  want a background image for it. As far as I know, the only way I can use that background is to redraw it every time. But that drops my FPS count to 26 (it runs at 60fps). Is there any way to use an image as background w/o having to redraw it?

PD: My background image is actually a `Drawable`, I'm using its `draw(canvas)` method to draw it on the canvas.

Comment: Why not just set the background of your Activity to the desired background you want before starting your SurfaceView thread?

Comment: I tried that, but on every draw call, the surfaceview needs to clear the background, and I'm clearing it with canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK) which paints the background, leaving the layout with the image background not visible. And canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) doesnt work

Comment: If you want a background, why are you clearing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuffMode.CLEAR).